# Gridview not showing after Gridview RowCommand event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, rowcommand

I have a GridView that shows a list of restaurants and it's data from my database. In the last column I have a `ButtonField`. When the user clicks on the button, then the `RowCommand` fires and another GridView appears with the selected restaurant's reviews.

**The issue I am having is that while the RowCommand event is fired, the second GridView `gvReviews` does not show up at all.**

- I have tried to set the GridView's `visible` to true but that does not
  seem to work.
- I have tried to use a `TemplateField` with a `Button` instead but that doesn't work either.
- I have tried using `if (!IsPostback)` statement

Here's a snippet of my GridViews:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvRestaurants" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvRestaurants_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RestaurantID" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RestName" HeaderText="Restaurant" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RestAddr" HeaderText="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RestCity" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RestState" HeaderText="State" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RestZip" HeaderText="Zip Code" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryDesc" HeaderText="Category" />
                <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Reviews" CommandName="viewReviews" Text="View" ButtonType="Button" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvReviews" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RestaurantID" HeaderText="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RestName" HeaderText="Restaurant" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReviewDate" HeaderText="Date of Review" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FoodQuality" HeaderText="Food Quality" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceRating" HeaderText="Service" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AtmosphereRating" HeaderText="Atmosphere" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PriceRating" HeaderText="Price" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReviewText" HeaderText="Review" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Here's a snippet of the aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gvRestaurants.Visible = true;
            gvAllRestaurants.Visible = false;
            DataSet ds = p.SearchByCategory(ddCategories.SelectedItem.Value, ddCategories2.SelectedItem.Value);
            gvRestaurants.DataSource = ds;
            gvRestaurants.DataBind();
        }

 protected void gvRestaurants_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "viewReviews")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                GridViewRow row = gvRestaurants.Rows[index];

                int restID = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);

                gvReviews.DataSource = p.GetReview(restID);
                gvReviews.DataBind();

                gvRestaurants.Visible = false;
                gvReviews.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                string error = "There are no reviews for this restaurant.";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
            }
```

Here's a snippet of the methods i used:

```
public DataSet SearchByCategory(string category1, string category2)
        {
            DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();
            objCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objCmd.CommandText = "GetRestaurantByCategory";

            SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@theCategory", category1);
            SqlParameter sqlParameter2 = new SqlParameter("@theCategory2", category2);

            sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            sqlParameter.Size = 50;

            sqlParameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            sqlParameter2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            sqlParameter2.Size = 50;

            objCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter2);

            objDB.GetConnection().Open();
            DataSet ds = objDB.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCmd);
            objDB.CloseConnection();

            return ds;
        }

        public DataSet GetReview(int restaurant)
        {
            DBConnect objDB = new DBConnect();
            objCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objCmd.CommandText = "GetReviewByRestaurantID";

            SqlParameter sqlParameter = new SqlParameter("@theRestaurantID", restaurant);

            sqlParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            sqlParameter.Size = 4;

            objCmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParameter);

            objDB.GetConnection().Open();
            DataSet ds = objDB.GetDataSetUsingCmdObj(objCmd);
            objDB.CloseConnection();

            return ds;
        }
```

Here are my stored procedures used:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].GetRestaurantByCategory
    @theCategory varchar(50),
    @theCategory2 varchar(50)

AS
    SELECT rest.RestaurantID, rest.RestName, rest.RestAddr, rest.RestCity, rest.RestState, rest.RestZip, cat.CategoryDesc
    FROM Restaurants rest JOIN Categories cat ON rest.CategoryID = cat.CategoryID
    WHERE CategoryDesc = @theCategory OR CategoryDesc = @theCategory2

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].GetReviewByRestaurantID
    @theRestaurantID int

AS
    SELECT rest.RestaurantID, rest.RestName, rev.ReviewDate, rev.FoodQuality, rev.ServiceRating, rev.AtmosphereRating, rev.PriceRating, rev.ReviewText
    FROM Restaurants rest JOIN Reviews rev ON rest.RestaurantID = rev.RestaurantID
    WHERE Rest.RestaurantID = @theRestaurantID
```

Comment: Which gridview doesn't show ? `gvRestaurants` ?

Comment: @KobyDouek the `gvReviews`

Comment: Have you verified that `p.GetReview(restID)` returns data? If it returns an empty datatable, this could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GridView` doesn't show because you bind it to a `DataSet` instead of binding it directly to a `DataTable` within this `DataSet`.

Try changing this line:

```
gvReviews.DataSource = p.GetReview(restID);
```

To this:

```
gvReviews.DataSource = p.GetReview(restID).Tables[0];
```

Comment: I used `if (p.GetReview(restID).Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    string error = "dataset is empty";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
                }` to check and apparently it is showing as empty.

Comment: @pyuntae So that's another problem. if the table has no rows, the gridview won't show.

Comment: But my tables have data. Does this mean there's an error in my stored procedures?

Comment: Nevermind. I realized that I only had one review for one restaurant only and I was checking for other restaurants with no reviews. Thank you. Checking to see if the dataset was empty solved my brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

use this query

```
SELECT rest.RestaurantID, rest.RestName, rev.ReviewDate, rev.FoodQuality, rev.ServiceRating, rev.AtmosphereRating, rev.PriceRating, rev.ReviewText
    FROM Restaurants rest JOIN Reviews rev ON rev.RestaurantID = rest.RestaurantID
    WHERE Rest.RestaurantID = @theRestaurantID
```